# yt framework div for main component module

Tags: joomla2.5

Im using yt framework (joomla 2.5), in Firebug I see

```
<div style="width: 0px;float:right; display:none" id="yt_col2">
```

but this line is not in index.php file. Where can I find this line?

I checked many php files, no luck. Need to delete it as modules are not showing right.

thx.